# Java - Efficient way to find duplicate elements

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, time-complexity

Can anyone help me conceptually understand what options are available to me for the following:

I have an array of int elements, I'm looking for a way that I can see if any of these are duplicates. I am trying to keep time complexity in mind, and want a solution that is in `O(n)` time.

With this specific boundary in mind, I cannot use a nested for-loop to iterate through all n elements, since this array may contain tens of thousands of indicies.

Any ideas or suggestions that might help me?

Comment: If you sort them (O(n log n)), then once they are sorted, you only have to compare adjacent items. (Assuming you are looking for duplicates.)

Comment: What do you mean "any of these match"? Match what? Do you mean find duplicates?

Comment: Yes I am looking for duplicate elements.

Comment: If all your ints are in a fairly constrained range, you can go through it once (O(n)) and keep counts of the occurrences of each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `HashSet<T> set` from your `T[] array`.
If

```
set.size() != array.length
```

then you have duplicates

Making `HashSet` has `O(n)` complexity.

Do not forget about `equals` and `hashcode` overriding in `T`.

Comment: Working great for me. Thanks for your input!